# changing id of <td> in JQuery

Tags: jquery

How do you change the id of a td element in JQuery?

Comment: While possible I think it's not good practice.. what's your goal?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can use [attr](http://api.jquery.com/attr) and an [id selector](http://api.jquery.com/id-selector/):

```
var element = $('#currentId');
element.attr('id', 'newId');
```

You can also set it directly in pure JavaScript:

```
var td = document.getElementById('currentId');
td.id = 'newId';
```

Comment: The td will already have an id, how would I get the td from it's id?